# MobileFirst 7.1 Direct Update feature

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

When we use direct update feature, is there any way to know how many users actually got the update and how many are pending?

Answer (score 3):

As of this moment we do not have this feature, however you could add in custom analytics in the custom direct update listener. It's important to note that if there's a direct update pending, customers cannot use the app without accepting the direct update.

In onFinish, you could send a custom analytics log similar to below ([docs](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_customizing_direct_update_ui_android_wp8_ios.html)).
Then go into the analytics console and create a custom chart showing how many people successfully direct update such as over time. ([docs](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/moving-production/operational-analytics/)).

```
var directUpdateCustomListener = {
  onStart: function(totalSize){
    //show custom progress dialog
  },
  onProgress: function(status,totalSize,completedSize){
    //update custom progress dialog
  },
  onFinish: function(status){

    if (status == 'SUCCESS'){
      //show success message

      //send custom analytics
      WL.Analytics.log({directUpdate: "success"},"successful direct update");
      WL.Analytics.send();

      WL.Client.reloadApp();
    }
    else {
      //show custom error message

      //submitFailure must be called is case of error
      wl_directUpdateChallengeHandler.submitFailure();
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In one way of thinking, **all** of your users got the update...

Nobody can run the old version of the code, so if they're logged as an active user AFTER you submitted the release, then they have the update.

-Paul Horan-
IBM